# Laravel - Ocultar parent, cuando la relación retorne null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Como podria saber si mi relación retorna null y quitarlo del array.

```
$canal = session()->get('canal')['type'];
        $layouts = PlanogramacionLayoutCreated::with(['layout' => function($q) use($canal) {
           $q->where('canal', 'LIKE', '%'. ucfirst($canal). '%');

        }])
        ->get();
```

Estoy obteniendo  los datos del Modelo padre, se adjuntan sus hijos `layouts` pero tengo una valicación en el hijo, para hacer un filtro por canal y su coincidencia.

Quiero saber, como puedo ocultar el padre, en caso de que la relación venga vacia:

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
  layout_id: 12,
  img: "dasjdksajd8123123MDAs.jpg",
  layout: null
 }
]
```

Como puedo identificar si `layout` viene null, y si es así no me lo agregue a mis objectos. Se que puedo hacerlo con un `foreach` pero creo que no seria una buena practica, y es lo que busco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes limitar los resultados en función de la [existencia de la relación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) pasando el nombre de la relación a los métodos `has` y `orHas`. Usa los métodos `whereHas` y `orWhereHas` para poner condiciones "where" en tus consultas de `has`. Estos métodos te permiten agregar restricciones personalizadas a una restricción de relación.
Lo que para tu código se traduciría en:

```
$layouts = PlanogramacionLayoutCreated::whereHas('layout', function (Builder $query) use ($canal) {
    $query->where('canal', 'LIKE', '%'. ucfirst($canal). '%');
})
->with(['layout'])
->get();
```

Comment: Excelente, lo que buscaba. Saludos!